# Returning an extremely large JSON (1GB)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have RESTful API that returns some large JSON files. In some instance, the returned string could become more than 1GB. When that happens, I only get some part of the content, meaning, I'm returning an array of objects, but only the first item is returned. Is there a way to remove this limitation? Here's my code (which is pretty simple).

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("rest/result")]
public IActionResult GetResult(string requestId)
{
    var item = _service.GetItem(requestId);
    return item?.Result == null ? NotFound() : Ok(item.Result);
}
```

### Edit:

This seems to return the 1GB JSON string but I'm not sure it's exactly the same data:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("rest/result")]
public IActionResult GetResult(string requestId)
{
    var item = _service.GetItem(requestId);
    if (item?.Result == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(item.Result);
    return Content(json, "application/json");
}
```

Comment: How are you checking the response size to know only the first item is returned?

Comment: As an aside... In this code is `.Result` a property on a `Task<>`?  Or just coinsidence that the type returned here has a similarly named property?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1151987/3063273

Comment: 1GB of text is a truly massive amount of text. Are you certain that you can't simply get less data in the first place?

Comment: @MattThomas I save the file on the server before sending it to the client. The response size is more or less 1GB for this particular request.

Comment: I set the mentioned option on the other post but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Joe I wrote this API but I can't have much of a say in the data that they produce on the other side. I suggested that to the other sections of the company but I just want to fix it if possible.

Comment: @David similar name but no, it's a property named "Result" not a result of a Task.

Comment: I still wonder if you're running into some limitation with the JSON serializer. [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.maxdepth?view=net-6.0#system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions-maxdepth). Perhaps try a different serializer to see what effect that has?

Comment: You are going to run into all manner of issues with such large blob of text. Firewalls might choke on it, and web servers don't handle it well either, and clients may get out of memory exceptions if they are not streaming the content properly. Avoid it if you can

Comment: @MattThomas I'm not sure which method the `Ok(obj)` is using to create the JSON string but `JsonSerializer.Serialize(item.Result)` is returning a 1GB string without any issues. Do you know if it's different or not? I assumed that it should be something similar.

Comment: @Charlieface I totally agree with you and my colleagues said that they're going to break up the data into chunks but I'd like to know what's enforcing that limitation and how I can fix that.

Comment: Like I said, it could be anything along the way. Usual suspects are firewall or any other proxy, web server settings, web server or client memory capacity (this last is unlikely as you would have got an exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are, hitting a default response size limit. so to adjust the limit you could use ResponseBufferSize property in your startup.configureServices

```
services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MaxRequestBodySize = int.MaxValue;
    options.MaxRequestBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
    options.MaxResponseBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
});
```

but, returning extremely large file could reduce the performance and scalability of your application.
the other ways to handle your result is to use pagination by dividing your result in small chunks or zip your result by compressing it.